# Sliding a div in windows8

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

i have created a Windows 8 app using HTML & JavaScript.

Here i want to slide a div[contains two textbox and a button] from right side of the screen towards left.

hopes the question is clear.

Comment: Well doing it in javascript would be like reinventing the wheel.. Are you planning many animations using JS in the coming future? THen there are many JS libraries you could consider to work with.. But as a base, you may want to start using JQuery..

Comment: Read up on CSS3 transitions.  They will do all the animation for you.

Comment: Also use the in built animations to give your app a consistent feel with other windows 8 applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229780.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using the following piece of code:

```
CSS:
  position: fixed;  
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 308px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: bisque;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
```

Then in JavaScript I have just set the opacity property to one.

```
JS:

 (function () {
 "use strict";
 var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/default.html", {
     ready: function (element, options) {
         btnname.addEventListener("click", togglePanelUI, false);

         myPanel = element.querySelector("#divname");        }     //div name is name of div which u wants to slide
 });

 var animating = WinJS.Promise.wrap();
 var myPanel;
 function togglePanelUI() {               // If element is already animating, wait until current animation is complete before starting the show animation.
     animating = animating
        .then(function () {
            // Set desired final opacity on the UI element.
            myPanel.style.opacity = "1";

            // Run show panel animation.
            // Element animates from the specified offset to its actual position.
            // For a panel that is located at the edge of the screen, the offset should be the same size as the panel element.
            // When possible, use the default offset by leaving the offset argument empty to get the best performance.
            return WinJS.UI.Animation.showPanel(myPanel);
        });

}
})();
```

for more information regarding animations of windows 8, have a look at [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-the-Animation-787f3720)

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `$.animate` is fine for that, [see here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

However, using jQuery in Windows 8 Apps is problematic due to security restrictions, I've written a blog post on that and provided a windows 8 ready jQuery version there, take a look: http://www.incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development/

Comment: I would recommend a CSS transition like @jfriend00 mentioned. jQuery animations in Windows 8 are not hardware accelerated, but CSS3 transitions are.

Comment: jQuery is internally using css3 transitions, if they are supported. As far as I'm concerned, the javascript animation is only used as fallback for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using CSS transitions.

```
/* CSS */
#myDiv {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:relative;
    left:-300px;
    border:2px solid;
    transition:1s;
}
```

Then in JavaScript you simply set the `left` property programmatically. In my case I did it in response to a button click.

```
// js
element.querySelector("#go").onclick = function(e) {
    element.querySelector("#myDiv").style.left = "0px";
};
```

And there you have it. Hardware accelerated and everything.

Comment: thanks a lot fr the code @foster. 
but the code shows the div instantly, instead of sliding the div.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the WinJS native animations library. For your can [WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701582.aspx) or [WinJS.UI.Animation.showPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230467.aspx) could be useful.